# SqlConnection in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, database, windows-phone-7, ado.net

Is it possibe to save date in remote database (on server) by mobile with WP7?
 I wolud like to use ADO.NET and insert some values. If it is not possible what else can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't - I'm 100% positive you can't in WP8 or WinRT, so I assume it also holds for WP7.

The best you can do is host a web-service somewhere that will provide a RESTful access to the database, then use `WebClient` (or whatever way you prefer to make a HTTP request) in the phone app to call the service.

Comment: 100% is a bit strong... there is a `Socket` library, so *technically* somebody could go in and re-engineer the entire stack... not sure that is very likely, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell In absolute terms, you're *absolutely* (pun intended) right. Realistically, as you pointed out, I doubt that's going to happen ;)

Comment: actually, I'm looking at the MS-SSTDS specification right now, thinking "that might be an interesting project"

Comment: Tabular Data Stream Protocol? Have to say, I have never heard of it before, but it does look interesting indeed. I wonder though how it would work in practice and if it could gain any significant traction...

Comment: It is basically just how SqlConnection talks to SQL-Server - the raw protocol (typically implemented on top of TCP). If someone wrote a TDS lib, then could be used without needing ADO.NET / SqlConnection / etc

Comment: The code is in github at https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Tds

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very cool tutorial :
http://studentguru.gr/b/dt008/archive/2010/12/02/querying-a-database-on-windows-phone-7-using-wcf.aspx